# Find JUnit 3 tests that are not included in any suite?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

If someone writes a new unit test but they forget to add it to a suite, the continuous build will continue to pass happily even if someone later breaks the test. Is there a way to discover JUnit tests that aren't included in a suite?

**EDIT**
I know I could move to JUnit 4 but then the question becomes, how do I find tests that are missing the @Test annotation?

Comment: Test that is missing @Test annotation is not a test in JUnit4.

Comment: @grigory Of course, but it's a pretty common mistake.

Comment: my point was that with JUnit 3 your question is very sound: how to find tests (methods that start with test and belong to sub-class of TestCase) that don't belong to any test suite. With JUnit 4 the question becomes: how to find tests that are not tests.

Answer (score 1):

Move to junit4?

Comment: Not always possible.  There are some test frameworks, e.g. GWT test, that depend on TestCase.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the following:

1. Use some combination of `find` and `grep` to extract a list of supposed test class names; e.g. `grep` for files that contain `extend TestCase`.
2. Use some combination of `find` and `grep` on the test reports to extract a list of the test classes that were actually run.
3. Sort the two lists and compare them using `diff`.

There is a risk of false positives and false negatives; e.g. test classes that don't directly extend `TestCase` might slip through the net.  But this approach will give you a quick "first cut" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `TestSuite.tests()` you can produce list of tests (recursively) included in test suites (*list1*) and using Java reflection you can produce list of all tests (from classes that extend `TestCase`) (*list2*).

Then subtract *list1* from *list2* to produce list of tests not included in any suite.

The classpath should contain all test classes when running this Java program.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not manually creating test suites. Instead, make sure your build automatically runs all tests that are under your "tests" directory. Ant supports a way to do this with the <junit> element.

You could also create a suite that finds the tests to run by looking for all non-abstract classes that extend TestCase. You could roll your own reflective suite with [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) or search around for free implementations (see [How do I programmatically run all the JUnit tests in my Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411938/how-do-i-programmatically-run-all-the-junit-tests-in-my-java-application))